# springboot embedded tomcat and tomcat-embed-jasper

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot

I sometimes see these following declaration in pom.xml...

```
   <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    ....
```

as you can see, spring-boot-starter-web was declared as well
as tomcat-embed-jasper.

isn't it spring-boot-starter-web already have an embedded tomcat?
why some developers still declare tomcat-embed-jasper along with boot-starter-web? or is there any reason?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As you said, the `spring-boot-starter-web` includes the `spring-boot-starter-tomcat`. You could check it [here](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.springframework.boot%7Cspring-boot-starter-web%7C1.5.1.RELEASE%7Cjar)

The `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` includes the `tomcat-embed-core`. You could check it [here](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.springframework.boot%7Cspring-boot-starter-tomcat%7C1.5.1.RELEASE%7Cjar)

But, seems like `tomcat-embed-core` doesn't include `tomcat-embed-jasper`. In fact, is `tomcat-embed-jasper` who includes dependency with `tomcat-embed-core`. Check it [here](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.tomcat.embed%7Ctomcat-embed-jasper%7C9.0.0.M17%7Cjar)

Anyway, the `tomcat-embed-jasper` is marked as `provided`, so indicates that you expect the JDK or a container to provide the dependency at runtime. This scope is only available on the compilation and test classpath, and is not transitive.

In conclusion, the `spring-boot-starter-web` includes the tomcat embedded dependency but it doesn't includes the jasper embedded dependency, so that should be the reason to declare it separately.

Also, remember that using Spring IO Platform as parent you are able to manage dependencies easily. To know more about this you [could read my post](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-use-spring-io-platform-and-spring-boot-toge)

Hope it helps,

Comment: It might be worth adding that the reason why developers are adding `tomcat-embed-jasper` (in my understanding that was part of the question) usually will be that they want their embedded Tomcat to be able to compile jsp-files. Because that's what jasper does. `spring-boot-starter-web` does not include `tomcat-embed-jasper` so it has to be declared separately.
That also explains the dependencies. The embedded Tomcat does not need jasper to work, you can still use servlets or other web filters. But of course jasper needs a container to compile jsp-files for.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I followed the hierarchy mentioned by you, but for me "tomcat-embed-jasper" is not marked with "provided". Kindly help me to understand this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please note that Spring Boot recommends to avoid JSP as template engine, although it supports it. There are some known JSP limitations. Please check [Spring Boot Template Engines](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-template-engines) and [JSP Limitations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jsp-limitations).

Comment: @AshishBurnwal By provided, he means it is marked as provided in the question itself. Not in the actual poms being referred in the links.

Comment: without tomcat-embed-jasper (in absence of JSP compilation
), browser will not open JSP but download them as a TXT file

Answer (score 2):

Extended from jcgarcia's answer.

Even it is provided, but when you build as war, spring-boot-maven-plugin will include two more jar :
 ecj-3.12.3.jar
 tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.23.jar

Answer (score 1):

To those who are still facing this error in 2022 with Java Version 17, Maven Version 3.0.0 and Package Jar. I also ran into the same issue just now, seems like even though we set `<scope>Provided</scope>` Maven is not picking up the jar. What you can do instead is just take that  completely off while adding the dependency and run the Maven to install dependencies again. It will fix it for sure. So your pom.xml file will go:-

From

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

To

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

In [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/), do not use last version specially with (snapshot) like 3.2.0(snapshot) use lower version like 2.7.17 in this state  with lower version no problem by entering jasper dependency