# SpringBeanAutowiringSupport VS SpringBeanFacesELResolver

Tags: spring, jsf-2, oracle-adf

I want to ask to the expert over here which one is a better approach for injecting Spring bean inside of a JSF Managed Bean.

I have gone through many tutorials on this topic and there are 2 ways to achieve this.

1)By extending `SpringBeanAutowiringSupport` class

2)By registering `SpringBeanFacesELResolver` class in `faces-config.xml` file.

But option 2 is not working in case of an ADF Application.I am unable to figure out the reason.I have registered the `SpringBeanFacesELResolver` in `faces-config.xml` file but whether it has to be define in `adfc-config.xml` file I am not sure.

So,I have gone with Option 1.
So,I want to know is there any drawback of this approach?

Whether any extra configuration needed to make SpringBeanFacesELResolver worked for ADF application?

Comment: Maybe switching to CDI annotations is an option?

Comment: I don't think ADF is supporting cdi annotations it still uses managed bean concept.
CDI concept came to jsf with JSF2.3,in ADF it is using JSF2.1.

Comment: I've been using CDI with JSF since jsf version late 2.1.x... In 2.3 the `@ManagedBean` annotations also still work but are now officially deprecated. It is more container related than ADF related

Comment: I have JSF working with spring: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46187725/spring-boot-jsf-integration You shouldn't need to change `adfc-config`. How do you know the issue is ADF related? Do you have any trace/exception? Have you tried with any ADFless JSF application?