# Spring boot + Primefaces modular app don't see xhtml page

Tags: spring-boot, jsf, primefaces, modular

I have an modular application Spring boot + Primefaces project and when I start it, the server does not see the page. Project structure:

```
app_module
--src
---main
----java
-----org.example.model (where placed entities, and beans for Jsf and main Spring Boot class)
--pom.xml
presentation_module
--src
---main
----webapp
-----WEB-INF
------faces-config.xml
------web.xml
-----install.xhtml
--pom.xml
pom.xml(parent)
```

app_module pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>org.vozup.givemeroom</artifactId>
        <groupId>GiveMeRoom</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>givemeroom-app</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <build>
        <finalName>app</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

presentation_module pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>org.vozup.givemeroom</artifactId>
        <groupId>GiveMeRoom</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>givemeroom-presentation</artifactId>

    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>GiveMeRoom</groupId>
            <artifactId>givemeroom-app</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.primefaces/primefaces -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.faces/jsf-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>webapp</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.3</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

parent pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>GiveMeRoom</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.vozup.givemeroom</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1</version>

    <modules>
        <module>presentation_module</module>
        <module>app_module</module>
    </modules>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <dependencies>
                <!-- postgres java connector for PROD-->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                    <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <dependencies>
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.h2database/h2 for DEV-->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
                    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
                    <version>1.4.197</version>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>


    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- display active profile in compile phase -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-help-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>show-profiles</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>active-profiles</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="3.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <display-name>modwebapp</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Sevlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Sevlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>install.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd" version="2.0">
    <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>*</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>goToInstallPage</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/install.xhtml</to-view-id>
            <redirect/>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
</faces-config>
```

When I try to get to the page localhost:8080/install.xhtml I get a Whitelabel Error Page error 404.
Maybe I don’t collect the project properly. Please help, thank you!

Comment: There is also a good answer for getting Spring Boot working with JSF (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46187725/spring-boot-jsf-integration?noredirect=1). Did you already check this?

Comment: I can't recommend the project JoinFaces enough.  It solves all of these problems allowing you to use Primefaces or any JSF stack in a Spring Boot app.  http://joinfaces.org/

Comment: When I have a single-module application, everything works. I think there is an error in the assembly.

Comment: Run your application in jsf development mode. Errors? Deployment errors?