# How to use Spring boot 3 with JSF?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jsf, build.gradle

I'm trying to create a JSF project managed by Spring boot 3.0. But it doesn't work no matter how I do it. I can't find any example on the web.

My dependencies:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:3.0.2'
implementation 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:10.1.5'
implementation 'org.glassfish:jakarta.faces:4.0.1'
testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:3.0.2'
```

My MainApplication class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ManagementClientApplication implements ServletContextAware {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ManagementClientApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean<FacesServlet> servletRegistrationBean() {
        ServletRegistrationBean<FacesServlet> servletRegistrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean<>(new FacesServlet(), "*.xhtml");
        servletRegistrationBean.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        return servletRegistrationBean;
    }

    @Override
    public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
        servletContext.setInitParameter("com.sun.faces.forceLoadConfiguration", Boolean.TRUE.toString());
        servletContext.setInitParameter("jakarta.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS", "true");
    }
}
```

My config webapp/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
    version="2.2">

    <application>
        <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver
        </el-resolver>
    </application>

</faces-config>
```

A test XHTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
<h:head>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <h:outputText id="greeting" value="Hello world !" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Logs :

```
2023-02-02T17:21:10.844+01:00  INFO 6312 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-02-02T17:21:10.845+01:00  INFO 6312 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 738 ms
2023-02-02T17:21:11.133+01:00 ERROR 6312 --- [           main] jakarta.faces                            : Unable to obtain InjectionProvider from init time FacesContext. Does this container implement the Mojarra Injection SPI?
2023-02-02T17:21:11.149+01:00 ERROR 6312 --- [           main] jakarta.faces                            : L’application n’a pas été initialisée correctement au démarrage. Impossible de localiser la Fabrique : jakarta.faces.context.FacesContextFactory. Attempting to find backup.
2023-02-02T17:21:11.150+01:00 ERROR 6312 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Servlet.init() for servlet [facesServlet] threw exception

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory jakarta.faces.context.FacesContextFactory. 
    at jakarta.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.notNullFactory(FactoryFinderInstance.java:497) ~[jakarta.faces-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at jakarta.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getFactory(FactoryFinderInstance.java:190) ~[jakarta.faces-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at jakarta.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:263) ~[jakarta.faces-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.acquireFacesContextFactory(FacesServlet.java:493) ~[jakarta.faces-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
```

Links I looked at:

[How to properly configure Jakarta EE libraries in Maven pom.xml for Tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65703840/how-to-properly-configure-jakarta-ee-libraries-in-maven-pom-xml-for-tomcat/65704617#65704617)
[Spring Boot JSF Integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46187725/spring-boot-jsf-integration)

[Spring Boot JSF Integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46187725/spring-boot-jsf-integration)

The project with Spring boot 2 and Javax that I tried to reproduce:

https://github.com/xtremebiker/jsf-spring-boot

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I can't find anything on the web. Any help would be welcome.

Thank you all

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [JoinFaces](https://github.com/joinfaces/joinfaces) starter.

As written on [Mojarra](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra), you need more dependencies.

```
implementation group: 'org.jboss.weld.servlet', name: 'weld-servlet-shaded', version: '5.1.0.Final'
```

Don't create FacesServlet yourself. `ServletContainerInitializer` does that.

But if you use embedded server, you should run two of them. Because [Spring Boot doesn't run](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#web.servlet.embedded-container.context-initializer) the initializers.

```java
@Bean
public ServletContextInitializer facesInitializer() {
    return new JsfInitializer();
}
```

```java
import org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.EnhancedListener;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializer;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletContext;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import com.sun.faces.config.FacesInitializer;

public class JsfInitializer implements ServletContextInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext context) throws ServletException {
        EnhancedListener cdiInitializer = new EnhancedListener();
        cdiInitializer.onStartup(null, context);

        ServletContainerInitializer facesInitializer = new FacesInitializer();
        facesInitializer.onStartup(null, context);
    }
}
```

After packaging to jar with Spring Boot, you get problems with CDI and static resources. I know 3 variants to fix this.

1. Use maven-jar-plugin and maven-dependency-plugin to copy dependencies to separate directory
2. Implement `org.jboss.weld.environment.deployment.discovery.BeanArchiveHandler` and register to `META-INF/services`.
   Add jar root to tomcat resources:

```
context.getResources().createWebResourceSet(ResourceSetType.RESOURCE_JAR, "/", jarRoot, "/META-INF/resources");
```

3. Or move all Faces beans and static to a separate jar-module.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
implementation 'org.glassfish:jakarta.faces:3.0.4'
```

I did not figure out the root cause (conflict?) yet but, I have noticed that any versions above 3.0.4 cause the exception you are getting. I got the same.
This worked for me:

```
implementation  'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:3.0.1'
implementation  'org.glassfish:jakarta.faces:3.0.4' 
providedRuntime 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:11.0.0-M6'
```