# Spring Boot Application Error Jslt/jsp tags giving exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

> Error
>
> > Whitelabel Error Page
> >     This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon Apr 27 21:00:28 BST 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

**controller**

```
package com.sales.controllers;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.sales.models.Product;
import com.sales.services.ProductService;
```

@Controller
    public class MainController {

```
@Autowired
ProductService ps;

@RequestMapping(value = "/showProducts.html")
public String getProducts(Model model) {
    ArrayList<Product> products =  ps.getAllProducts();
    model.addAttribute("products", products);
    return "listProducts";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/addProduct.html")
public String addPerson(Model model) {
    Product p = new Product();

    model.addAttribute("products", p);
    return "addProduct";
}

}
```

**listProducts.js**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>List of Products</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>List of Products</h1>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Product ID</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Quantity in Stock</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<c:forEach items="${products}" var="product">
  <tr> 
    <td>${product.pId}</td>
    <td>${product.pDesc}</td>
    <td>${product.qtyInStock}</td>
  </tr>
</c:forEach>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><a href="\">Home</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**product class**

```
package com.sales.models;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;

@Entity
@Table(name="PRODUCTS")
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="PID")
    private Long pId;

    @Column(name="PDESC")
    @NotBlank
    private String pDesc;

    @Column(name="QTYINSTOCK")
    @Min(value=0)
    private int qtyInStock;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="prod")
    private List<Order> ordersForProduct = new ArrayList<Order>();

    public Long getpId() {
    return pId;
    }

    public void setpId(Long pId) {
        this.pId = pId;
    }

    public String getpDesc() {
        return pDesc;
    }

    public void setpDesc(String pDesc) {
        this.pDesc = pDesc;
    }

    public int getQtyInStock() {
        return qtyInStock;
    }

    public void setQtyInStock(int qtyInStock) {
        this.qtyInStock = qtyInStock;
    }

    public List<Order> getOrdersForProduct() {
        return ordersForProduct;
    }

    public void setOrdersForProduct(List<Order> ordersForProduct) {
        this.ordersForProduct = ordersForProduct;
    }

}
```

**run class**

```
package com.sales;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class FinalProjV1Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(FinalProjV1Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.sales</groupId>
<artifactId>Sales</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>FinalProjV1</name>
<description>Sales Application</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


</project>
```

Comment: if i remove this <%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%> from listProducts.js page the it displays fine but the forloop doesnt work

Comment: first "guess": omit `provided` scope from `jstl` dependency! (https://stackoverflow.com/q/4928271/592355 ...)

Comment: ..see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42154614/592355)

Comment: omitted provided but still gets error

Comment: Solved by installing java development tools 8 and setting the environment variables.