# Tomcat Jasper Dependen

Tags: tomcat, spring-tools-4

I am trying to find out the Tomcat version for the sts 4 but could not find as there are no maven dependency folder unlike the previous versions of the spring boot. so can anyone please tell me the version of Tomcat used in STS 4 pparticularly so that I can embed the Tomcat Jasper separately.???

Answer (score 0):

Spring Tools 4 for Eclipse (STS4) does not include a specific Tomcat version and does not require you to use a specific Tomcat version.

Spring Boot comes with an embedded Tomcat server by default, so if you create and run a Spring Boot application, an embedded Tomcat is started - at least in case you decided to include the Spring Boot Web starter. But that is totally independent of the IDE that you use.

With regards to the "how to include Jasper" part of the question, there are plenty of questions on SO around this, e.g. [springboot embedded tomcat and tomcat-embed-jasper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42154614/springboot-embedded-tomcat-and-tomcat-embed-jasper) gives some insights.